# Round a number to nearest .25 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I want to convert all numbers to the nearest .25

So...

```
5 becomes 5.00
2.25 becomes 2.25
4 becomes 4.00
3.5 becomes 3.50
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to make any sense. All your numbers are becoming themselves, there's no rounding being done.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Here’s an implementation of what rslite said:

```
var number = 5.12345;
number = (Math.round(number * 4) / 4).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Here it is as a function:


    var roundNearQtr = function(number) {
      return (Math.round(number * 4) / 4).toFixed(2);
    };

Comment: I made a function that does it for arbitrary decimals (ex. 0.25 or 0.3) rather than /4...  `function roundFloat(value, toNearest, fixed){
  return (Math.ceil(value / toNearest) * toNearest).toFixed(fixed);
}`

Comment: I made a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/plong0/pen/NrrRdp?editors=1111) to play with rounding floats and rounding integers using this technique

Comment: @plong0 your solution is good. You could have published here as an answer apart from publishing it in codepen

Answer (score 72):

Multiply by 4, round to integer, divide by 4 and format with two decimals.

Comment: @ e.c.ho - Yep. exact reason. Although the theory was correct. I've upvoted him now because he was technically correct.

Answer (score 12):

If speed is your concern, note that you can get about a 30% speed improvement by using:

```
var nearest = 4;
var rounded = number + nearest/2 - (number+nearest/2) % nearest;
```

From my website: http://phrogz.net/round-to-nearest-via-modulus-division
Performance tests here: http://jsperf.com/round-to-nearest

Comment: Great answer... Change to this if you have negative numbers.

var rounded = number + nearest/2 - Math.abs((number+nearest/2) % nearest);

Comment: @Lenny But note that when you do that, you are invoking a function call (`Math.abs`) and so you will lose the speed benefit.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a generic function to do rounding. In the examples above, 4 was used because that is in the inverse of .25. This function allows the user to ignore that detail. It doesn't currently support preset precision, but that can easily be added.

```
function roundToNearest(numToRound, numToRoundTo) {
    numToRoundTo = 1 / (numToRoundTo);

    return Math.round(numToRound * numToRoundTo) / numToRoundTo;
}
```

Comment: This requires one extra operation than `Math.round(num / multiple) * multiple;`. *However*, it is my preferred version for one major reason: it doesn't give results like "0.3000000000000004" for `Round(.2 + .1, .1)`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is @Gumbo's answer in a form of a function:

```
var roundNearQtr = function(number) {
  return (Math.round(number * 4) / 4).toFixed(2);
};
```

You can now make calls:

```
roundNearQtr(5.12345); // 5.00
roundNearQtr(3.23); // 3.25
roundNearQtr(3.13); // 3.25
roundNearQtr(3.1247); // 3.00
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function roundToInc(num, inc) {
    const diff = num % inc;
    return diff>inc/2?(num-diff+inc):num-diff;
}

> roundToInc(233223.2342343, 0.01)
233223.23
> roundToInc(505, 5)
505
> roundToInc(507, 5)
505
> roundToInc(508, 5)
510
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below function, hope it helps

```
function roundByQuarter(value) {
    var inv = 1.0 / 0.25;
    return Math.round(value * inv) / inv;
}
```

Call the function as below, will result the nearest Quarter value, that is it will not return .32, .89, .56 but will return .25, .75, .50 decimals only.

```
roundByQuarter(2.74) = 2.75

roundByQuarter(2.34) = 2.25

roundByQuarter(2.94) = 3.00

roundByQuarter(2.24) = 2.25
```

Answer (score 0):

A very good approximation for rounding:

```
function Rounding (number, precision){

  var newNumber;
  var sNumber = number.toString();

  var increase = precision + sNumber.length - sNumber.indexOf('.') + 1;

  if (number < 0)
    newNumber = (number -  5 * Math.pow(10,-increase));
  else
  newNumber = (number +  5 * Math.pow(10,-increase));

  var multiple = Math.pow(10,precision);
  return Math.round(newNumber * multiple)/multiple;
}
```

Comment: How is this better than the other answers? The other ones seem much shorter. (I could parse the code to try to figure out what advantage it has, but it's faster to just ask. ^_^)