# How to round an integer up or down to the nearest 10 using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, I would like to round a number passed by a user to the nearest 10. For example, if 7 is passed I should return 10, if 33 is passed I should return 30.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Divide the number by `10`, round the result and multiply it with `10` again, for example:

1. `33 / 10 = 3.3`
2. `3.3 rounded = 3`
3. `3 × 10 = 30`

```js
console.log(Math.round(prompt('Enter a number', 33) / 10) * 10);
```

Comment: This technique also works using `Math.floor`, if you want to prevent rounding upwards

Comment: You can use Math.ceil method to round up.

Comment: @brainstormerdanesh, just comment if you disagree or want to improve the answer's code/intent. Even better: post your edit (might got rejected) as own answer.

Answer (score 30):

```
Math.round(x / 10) * 10
```

Answer (score 26):

Where `i` is an int.

To round down to the nearest multiple of 10 i.e.

> 11 becomes 10
>   19 becomes 10
>   21 becomes 20

```
parseInt(i / 10, 10) * 10;
```

---

To round up to the nearest multiple of 10 i.e.

> 11 becomes 20
>   19 becomes 20
>   21 becomes 30

```
parseInt(i / 10, 10) + 1 * 10;
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be: (parseInt(i / 10, 10) + 1) * 10;  ?

Comment: @user3924331, you are right. The correct answer is (parseInt(i / 10, 10) + 1) * 10; Edits must be at least 6 characters so it is not possible to add just those two parenthesis... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Up to the nearest 10 adds +10 for value 100, so it becomes 110. Down to nearest 10 does not subtract -10 for 100, so 100 stays 100.

Comment: This does not work when i is 10 or more. A better solution would be Math.floor(i / 10) * 10

Comment: parseInt(i / 10, 10) * 10;  Maybe it'll work

Answer (score 9):

I needed something similar, so I wrote a function. I used the function for decimal rounding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27861660/271351), and since I also use it for integer rounding, I will set it as the answer here too. In this case, just pass in the number you want to round and then 10, the number you want to round to.

```
function roundToNearest(numToRound, numToRoundTo) {
    return Math.round(numToRound / numToRoundTo) * numToRoundTo;
}
```

Comment: I like that you've made it into a function, but does this give different output from the accepted answer, and if not, why have you used a different formula?

Comment: It returns the same value, but the formula is different because it makes it easier to use. For example, if you want to round to the nearest `.25`, you can simply use `.25` as the second argument. If you were to use the formulas in the other answers you'd have to use `4` as the second argument when you want to round to `.25`, which is counter-intuitive.

Comment: can you prove that? i've just done some testing in the console & the accepted answer returns the correct answer using `.25` as the 2nd argument - I made it into a one liner function `function roundTo(x,y){return Math.round(x / y) * y}`

Comment: @RozzA, you're right. I was thinking of the answers in another similar question. I'll simplify my function.