# Round number up to the nearest multiple of 3

Tags: javascript, integer, rounding

How would I go about rounded a number up the nearest multiple of 3?

i.e.

```
25 would return 27
1 would return 3
0 would return 3
6 would return 6
```

Comment: 0 would return 3???? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: How to round an integer up or down to the nearest 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684202/jquery-how-to-round-an-integer-up-or-down-to-the-nearest-10)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
    if(n > 0)
        return Math.ceil(n/3.0) * 3;
    else if( n < 0)
        return Math.floor(n/3.0) * 3;
    else
        return 3;
```

Comment: dont think this would work, would only bring back the same number

Comment: Why is that? Say we have 7 and we want 9, 7/3=2.33333, ceil(2.3333)=3, 3*3=9.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Cambium is right - it works, because it rounds the n/3 up to the nearest whole number before multiplying by 3 again.

Comment: @RobertPitt: This works just as it should! you should try it before claiming it isn't correct.

Comment: @Sani Huttunen, that was my point, i was talking about the 0 issue, @Jens F, I did as this does not meet the OP's requirements :/ i know the math is right

Comment: It does look like the requirement is wrong, but thats not necessarily for developers to decide. Give the customer what they want, and then charge them through the nose for the subsequent change ;)

Comment: @RobertPitt: thanks, you were right, I overlooked the requirements :)

Comment: @PaulJWilliams: but since the customer's requirements are inconsistent with the problem statement, the only possible answer is `{25:27,1:3,0:3,6:6}[x]`. Even if you ignore the case with `x=0`, how can -1 round up to -3, if -3 is clearly smaller than -1? The correct answer to the stated problem would be `Math.ceil(x/3)*3`.

Comment: You can also write this answer as `return 3 * Math[n > 0 ? "ceil" : n < 0 ? "floor" : "exp"](n / 3.0);`

Answer (score 40):

Simply:

```
3.0*Math.ceil(n/3.0)
```

?

Comment: Apart from the op's requirement for n = 0, this is should be higher.

Comment: to comply with the mad requirement, add `if (n === 0) return 3` :P

Comment: This rounds either up or down to the nearest multiple instead of always rounding up, or for example `3.0*Math.round(25/3.0)` returns 24 instead of 27.

Comment: Oh yea it should be Math.ceil

Comment: Change `ceil` to `floor` for it to always round down to the nearest multiple. `ceil` to `round` in order to round to the closest multiple.

Answer (score 20):

Here you are!

```
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(num) {
    var resto = this%num;
    if (resto <= (num/2)) { 
        return this-resto;
    } else {
        return this+num-resto;
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
y = 236.32;
x = y.roundTo(10);

// results in x = 240

y = 236.32;
x = y.roundTo(5);

// results in x = 235
```

Comment: `Number(1).roundTo(3)` returns 0.

Comment: @OrangeDog this is perfect! In your example, 1.6 or more should result in 3. A smaller number will give 0.

Comment: The question specifically says (and gives examples) that all numbers should be rounded up.

Comment: The else statement is useless

Answer (score 12):

I'm answering this in psuedocode since I program mainly in SystemVerilog and Vera (ASIC HDL).  % represents a modulus function.

```
round_number_up_to_nearest_divisor = number + ((divisor - (number % divisor)) % divisor)
```

This works in any case.

The modulus of the number calculates the remainder, subtracting that from the divisor results in the number required to get to the next divisor multiple, then the "magic" occurs.  You would think that it's good enough to have the single modulus function, but in the case where the number is an exact multiple of the divisor, it calculates an extra multiple.  ie, 24 would return 27.  The additional modulus protects against this by making the addition 0.

Comment: `function roundUpMultiple(num,div) {return num+((div-(num%div))%div)}`

Comment: This results in loss of significance for a number that is smaller than 0 but larger than -1, so that for example `n=-.1;d=3;n+(d-n%d)%d` returns `8.326672684688674e-17`. This method can also be used to round a number down (instead of up) to a multiple of `d` by making `d` negative, but then it results in loss of significance for a number that is larger than 0 but smaller than 1, so that `d=-3;[-3,-1,-.1,0,.1,3].map(function(x){return x+(d-x%d)%d})` returns `[-3,-3,-3,0,-8.326672684688674e-17,3]`.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in a comment to the accepted answer, you can just use this:

```
Math.ceil(x/3)*3
```

(Even though it does not return 3 when `x` is 0, because that was likely a mistake by the OP.)

Out of the nine answers posted before this one (that have not been deleted or that do not have such a low score that they are not visible to all users), only the ones by Dean Nicholson (excepting the issue with loss of significance) and beauburrier are correct. The accepted answer gives the wrong result for negative numbers and it adds an exception for 0 to account for what was likely a mistake by the OP. Two other answers round a number to the nearest multiple instead of always rounding up, one more gives the wrong result for negative numbers, and three more even give the wrong result for positive numbers.

Comment: Something to be aware of with this and the other's that make use of `ceil()` is Javascript's strangeness with ceil and very small decimal values. Note these examples:

`Math.ceil(216.3/3)*3` = 219.

`Math.ceil(216.00000000000003/3)*3` = 219.

`Math.ceil(216.000000000000003/3)*3` = 216.

One extra decimal place breaks ceil and hence your attempt to get the nearest multiple of 3. Depending your needs, you might be able to `Math.round(n)` first.

Answer (score 6):

This function will round up to the nearest multiple of whatever factor you provide.
It will not round up 0 or numbers which are already multiples.

```
round_up = function(x,factor){ return x - (x%factor) + (x%factor>0 && factor);}

round_up(25,3)
27
round up(1,3)
3
round_up(0,3)
0
round_up(6,3)
6
```

The behavior for 0 is not what you asked for, but seems more consistent and useful this way. If you did want to round up 0 though, the following function would do that:

```
round_up = function(x,factor){ return x - (x%factor) + ( (x%factor>0 || x==0) && factor);}

round_up(25,3)
27
round up(1,3)
3
round_up(0,3)
3
round_up(6,3)
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Makram's approach, and incorporating @Adam's subsequent comments, I've modified the original Math.prototype example such that it accurately rounds negative numbers in both zero-centric and unbiased systems:

```
Number.prototype.mround = function(_mult, _zero) {

  var bias = _zero || false;
  var base = Math.abs(this);
  var mult = Math.abs(_mult);

  if (bias == true) {
    base = Math.round(base / mult) * _mult;
    base = (this<0)?-base:base ;
  } else { 
    base = Math.round(this / _mult) * _mult;
  }

  return parseFloat(base.toFixed(_mult.precision()));

}

Number.prototype.precision = function() {
  if (!isFinite(this)) return 0;
  var a = this, e = 1, p = 0;
  while (Math.round(a * e) / e !== a) { a *= 10; p++; }
  return p;
}
```

Examples:
(-2).mround(3) returns -3;
(0).mround(3) returns 0;
(2).mround(3) returns 3;
(25.4).mround(3) returns 24;
(15.12).mround(.1) returns 15.1

Answer (score 1):

(n - n mod 3)+3

Comment: javascript's mod operator is %, additionally it will (*mistakenly*) round up even numbers that are already multiple's of 3..

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var modulus = 3;
    for (i=0; i < 21; i++) {
        $("#results").append("<li>" + roundUp(i, modulus) + "</li>")
    }
});


function roundUp(number, modulus) {
    var remainder = number % modulus;
    if (remainder == 0) {
        return number;
    } else {
        return number + modulus - remainder;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Round up to nearest multiple of 3:
<ul id="results">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general answer that might help somebody with a more general problem: if you want to round numbers to multiples of a fraction, consider using a library. This is a valid use case in GUI where decimals are typed into input and for instance you want to coerce them to multiples of 0.25, 0.2, 0.5 etc. Then the naive approach won't get you far:

```
function roundToStep(value, step) {
  return Math.round(value / step) * step;
}

console.log(roundToStep(1.005, 0.01)); // 1, and should be 1.01
```

After hours of trying to write up my own function and looking up npm packages, I decided that [Decimal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js/v/3.0.0) gets the job done right away. It even has a `toNearest` method that does exactly that, and you can choose whether to round up, down, or to closer value (default).

```
const Decimal = require("decimal.js")

function roundToStep (value, step) {
  return new Decimal(value).toNearest(step).toNumber();
}

console.log(roundToStep(1.005, 0.01)); // 1.01
```

[RunKit example](https://runkit.com/hyvyys/round-to-step/2.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Using remainder operator (modulus):

```
(n - 1 - (n - 1) % 3) + 3
```

Answer (score 0):

By the code given below use can change any numbers and you can find any multiple of any number

```js
let numbers = [8,11,15];
let multiple = 3
let result = numbers.map(myFunction);
function myFunction(n){
let answer = Math.round(n/multiple) * multiple ;
    if (answer <= 0)
    return multiple
    else
    return answer
}
console.log("Closest Multiple of " + multiple  + " is " + result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(x%3==0)
    return x
else
    return ((x/3|0)+1)*3
```

Comment: Doesn't satisfy the (mad) requirement when n == 0.

Comment: This is literally the only correct answer to this question o_O

Comment: O_o what? `x/3|0` is the same as `Math.floor(x/3)` except 27% slower, according to [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/74). Also, if `x=-4`, then it outputs 0, which is clearly incorrect, no matter how you define rounding.