# Round Up to the nearest multiple of 12

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round number up to the nearest multiple of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254047/round-number-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-3)

I need a javascript call that will round numbers up to the nearest multiple of 12.

Some examples:

1 -> 12

7 -> 12

14 -> 24

27 -> 36

Does anyone know of a good method for doing this? All I can think of is "If between 1-11, make it 12. If between 13-23, make it 24, etc." But that doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: Divide by 12, round up, multiply by 12.

Comment: @epascarello I apologize if it's a duplicate, I didn't see it before posting this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```
var n = 13;
var next = Math.ceil(n/12) * 12;
```

Comment: This will round to 0 for n < 12.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, that is incorrect, it will not be zero for all values less than zero. It will round up to the closest 12 towards zero. aka -25 would be -24.  Zero would be zero since zero is a multiple of 12.

Comment: interesting. It a lot of languages 5/12 will result in integer division, Javascript appears to keep the result as a floating point. At least this is what I got from chrome: `5/12 =
0.4166666666666667`, I would expect 0 though.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That's because JavaScript doesn't have anything else than floating point. (except as an intermediary step when using binary (as in bit-level) operators)

Answer (score 4):

For positive integers:

```
ceiling(n/12.0) * 12
```

For negative integers:

```
floor(n/12.0) * 12
```

For zero:

```
return 12
```

Comment: What if it is negative zero? ;)

Comment: It probably wont be, I hear that number is rare.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nearest(i) {
    return Math.floor((i-1)/12)*12+12;
}
```

Comment: +1 for ceil by epascarello which does the same thing but in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function roundIt(n) {
    return Math.ceil(n / 12) * 12;
}
```