# How to output same line of HTML without loop

Tags: php, html, css, loops

The situation I am in here is I am building a web app which gets an item from an SQL table and does some math to calculate how many you could afford with a certain amount of money. To provide a specific example if a user had £1,000,000 and wanted to see how many HB Pencils this would buy the math would be 1000000 / 0.08. I would then display an icon as a visual representation for each. Now obviously no one wants to look at that many icons so I have a weight field in the DB which for pencils happens to be 10,000 so i would only be displaying 12,500 icons however this is still way too slow when outputting them via a while loop. The only thing I can think it to know the height/width of the icon and create a DIV that big and have the icon tiled a BG image.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: Good idea..! Give it a try :)

Comment: _" The only thing I can think it to know the height/width of the icon and create a DIV that big and have the icon tiled a BG image."_ that's  how I would do it.

Comment: Why not use a logarithmic scale on this as 12,500 is still huge, or perhaps icons scaled in size to match the count.

Comment: BTW, I would guess that the downvotes are due to having no code to look at, but personally I don’t think that your current code is necessary for this question, given that you are looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: okay working this way and my current issue now is that the height of the container must always be an exact multiple of the icon height. anyway to find the nearest multiple of 47 to an exact number. e.g im currently getting height 293.75 and i need to find the next highest number divisible by 47

Comment: Divide by 47, round up, and multiply by 47. `ceil(n / 47) * 47`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254047/round-number-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a DIV with an exact height so it contained the number of icons I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't see any use in displaying 12,500 icons. Does the end user have to count them? Perhaps you can show 12,5 and indicate that 1 pencil image is 1000 pencils. Also make sure that your dom manipulation happens at the end of your loop and you don't manipulate the dom for every item.

Comment: Hi - the use is simply a visual representation of how much you can really do with large sums of money. I personally think the only way it is to be solved is to use my original implementation by figuring out how big the container should be and setting the icon as a background image.