# Find nearest next even 100

Tags: javascript, numbers, zero

In javascript what's the simplest way to find the next even 100 ("even 100" = 200, 400, etc.) that's closest to the given number. For ex: 1723 should return 1800, 1402 should return 1600, 21 should return 200, 17659 should return 17800 etc. I have the following that finds the nearest 100 next to the given_num but not the even 100

`(parseInt(((given_num + 99) / 100 )) * 100 )`

I can think of one way of getting the number without zeroes and checking if its odd/even to figure out next even number if its odd.But more curious to see if there's some simple/elegant way.

Comment: 1723 should give you 1900, not 1800, if the rule is to make sense.

Comment: I think he wants the next multiple of 200 ("even 200" = 200, 400, etc.)

Comment: @bmb: Ah! Okay....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254047/round-number-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-3

Comment: Divide by 200, round up, multiply by 200.

Comment: @bmb: LOL, *exactly* what my answer says. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [bmb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925970/find-nearest-next-even-100#comment67135733_39925970), it sounds like you want granularity of 200, not 100. If so:

Divide by 200, round up, multiply by 200:

```js
var tests = [
  {value: 1723, expect: 1800},
  {value: 1402, expect: 1600},
  {value: 21, expect: 200},
  {value: 17659, expect: 17800}
];
tests.forEach(test);
function test(entry) {
  var result = Math.ceil(entry.value / 200) * 200;
  console.log({
    value: entry.value,
    expect: entry.expect,
    result: result
  });
}
```

If you really want to work by rounding up to the "next 100," then the result for 1723 must be 1900 if the result for 1402 is 1600, and you do it by dividing by 100, rounding up, multplying by 100, and adding 100 (or dividing by 100, rounding up, adding 1, and multiplying by 100, which is the same thing):

```js
var tests = [
  {value: 1723, expect: 1800},
  {value: 1402, expect: 1600},
  {value: 21, expect: 200},
  {value: 17659, expect: 17800}
];
tests.forEach(test);
function test(entry) {
  var result = Math.ceil(entry.value / 100) * 100 + 100;
  console.log({
    value: entry.value,
    expect: entry.expect,
    result: result
  });
}
```

Comment: yeah this works :) this was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Call recursively if not even, add `1` to go the next 100 etc

```js
function closestEven(n) {
 var x = Math.ceil(n / 100 ), y = x * 100;
 return x % 2 === 0 ? y : closestEven(y+1);
}

console.log( closestEven(1723) ); // 1800
console.log( closestEven(1402) ); // 1600
console.log( closestEven(21) );   //  200
console.log( closestEven(17659)); // 17800
```

Comment: Add 100 to get there faster, or conditionally return `y+100` :)

Comment: @Traktor53 - Adding just `1` is enough, as it rounds up to the nearest `100` anyway, it doesn't iterate through all 99 numbers to get there.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```js
var given_num = 1723;
var result = (given_num) + (100 - ((given_num + 100) % 100));
alert(result);
```

Comment: This won't work for 1402.. It returns 1500 but it should be 1600

Comment: ...and "try this" answers are not useful. Say *what* you did, and *why*.