# Round the number with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to round the numbers like this:

```
Value   Expected
0,523%  1%
2,235%  2,5%
-0,081% -0,5%
-1,081% -1,5%
```

How can I do this with JavaScript?

Solution:

```
  static round (num) {
    const abs = Math.abs(num);
    const sign = num < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    return sign * (abs % 1 > 0.5 ? Math.ceil(abs) : Math.floor(abs) + 0.5) }
}
```

I used Excel for it =round(Value/Granularity)*Granularity but I tried it in JavaScript not working.

```
 static calc(num){
    const granularitiy = 0.00005;
    let calc = Math.round((num / granularitiy)) * granularitiy;
    return calc;
  }
```

My granularity value is 0.00005;

Comment: show your work here

Comment: Could you please add a description of how you want the numbers to be rounded? To the nearest 0.5? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: There's no built-in for this kind of rounding. You'll have to **1)** define precisely a test unit **2)** write the code yourself for your specific requirement. Note that a specific rounding function isn't really easy to write.

Comment: You want to round positive numbers *up* to the nearest .5, and negative numbers *down* to the nearest .5…?

Comment: Do you mean, round to the nearest multiple of 0.5 away from zero?

Comment: This seems like a bad way to round.  You'll end up with a huge gap between a `0.001` and a `-0.001`.  One will round all the way up to `0.5` and the other down to `-0.5`.  That's a huge gap.

Comment: This answer using .5 instead of 3 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254047/round-number-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-3

Comment: `function round (num) {
  const abs = Math.abs(num);
  const sign = num < 0 ? -1 : 1;

  return sign * (abs % 1 > 0.5 ? Math.ceil(abs) : Math.floor(abs) + 0.5) }`

Comment: How can I adjust it for negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Since on only want to round to .5 or round numbers, you can't simply use `Math.round(number)`.

The easiest way to do this would be to have something like:

```
Math.round(number*2)/2
```

This way, you'll alway have a number .5 or round.
If you want to round another way (ceil or floor), you can simply replace the Math.round by whatever you want.

Comment: This does not produce all wanted results

Comment: I'd like to make it more precise but we need more info from the op.