# Rounding a number to factors of 2.5 only

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I am tweaking a javascript project that works with weightlifting plates. Weight plate changes are in 2.5kg increments. I want to be able to take any number my script spits out and round it up or down to the nearest 2.5kg. So, an answer like 224 or 224.8 needs to round up to 225. Or 223 needs to round down to 222.5. It's ok if all numbers have a .0 in the decimal position as I can strip out the .0 later for "cosmetic" purposes by performing a replace function with the string.

I know that math.round is the key to all this, I just am not sure about how to go about telling it to round to 2.5 and not just to an integer or a certain number of decimal points.

To get my initial result I use:

y = (Math.round(z * 4) / 4).toFixed(1);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3254334/3389737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a complicated route and create your own function to do this, but the simplest way would be to use Math.ceiling. Essentially, the following should work.

```
2.5 * Math.ceil(z/2.5)
```

This will raise the number to the nearest integer after doing the division, then get the next highest. For instance, 224.8 would be divided by 2.5 to get something around 89.5 I think. This would be rounded to 90, and this would then be multiplied by 2.5 to get you 225. Only issue may be with some lower numbers, but seeing as what this program is for, I don't think that would be a real-life issue.

Comment: That worked fine.

var z =  (myNumber * 0.01);
var zzz = 2.5 * Math.ceil(z/2.5);
y = (Math.round(zzz * 4) / 4).toFixed(1);