# How to find the nearest larger number that is divisible by X Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

I have a math problem like this:
When I enter a number, I find the nearest larger number that is divisible by a number x

Example: x = 50 
Input = 20 => output = 50 
Input = 67 => output = 100 
Input = 200 => output = 200 
Input = 289 => output = 300 
Input = 999 => output = 1000  
.......

I have a function below, but is there a way to make it faster?

```js
console.log(roundNumber(199));

function roundNumber(n) {
  let x = 50;
  let flg = false;
  while (flg === false) {
    if (n > x) {
      x += 50;
    } else {
      flg = true;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: without `Math` functions ... `return (x - (n % x)) % x + n;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can divide the `input` value by 50, take the "floor", add 1, and then multiply by 50.

```
function roundNumber(n) {
  let x = 50;
  return (Math.floor((n + x - 1) / x)) * 50;
}
```

Whether this will be much faster is kind-of irrelevant, unless for some reason you're performing this operation thousands and thousands of times over a short interval.

Comment: Sorry! I just edited the question a bit, if `roundNumber(200)` the result is `250`, i want it to be `200`
Thank you!

Comment: @tranthaihoang oh right; there's a slight change, give me a sec

Comment: @tranthaihoang answer fixed now, sorry it's been a while since I've done this :)

Comment: thank you! I followed this suggestion, and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254047/round-number-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-3