# Round money to nearest 10 dollars in Javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding, currency

How can I round a decimal number in Javascript to the nearest 10? My math is pretty rubbish today, it could be the 2 hour sleep :/

**Some sample cases**

```
$2823.66  = $2820
$142.11 = $140
$9.49 = $10
```

I understand I probably need a combination of Math.round/floor but I can't seem to get expected result.

**Any help/pointers appreciated!**

**M**

Comment: Wow, 4 identical answers

Comment: Then that must be the right way to do it :-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their answers, I can't really choose which answer to accept so I'll give points to Toby who has the least! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: How to round an integer up or down to the nearest 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684202/jquery-how-to-round-an-integer-up-or-down-to-the-nearest-10)

Comment: To a senior user: could this question be edited, so it covers more programing languages as this is more of a mathematical question than a language specific one?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try

```
Math.round(val / 10) * 10;
```

Answer (score 12):

Use this function:

```
function roundTen(number)
{
  return Math.round(number/10)*10;
}



alert(roundTen(2823.66));
```

Answer (score 9):

To round a number to the nearest 10, first divide it by 10, then round it to the nearest 1, then multiply it by 10 again:

```
val = Math.round(val/10)*10;
```

[This page](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml) has some details. They go the other way (e.g., rounding to the nearest 0.01) but the theory and practice are identical - multiply (or divide), round, then divide (or multiply).

Answer (score 4):

10 * Math.round(val / 10)

Answer (score 2):

```
function round(number, multiplier) {
  multiplier = multiplier || 1;
  return Math.round(number / multiplier) * multiplier;
}

var num1 = 2823.66;
var num2 = 142.11;
var num3 = 9.49;

console.log(
  "%s\n%s\n%s", // just a formating thing
  round(num1, 10), // 2820
  round(num2, 10), // 140
  round(num3, 10)  // 10
);
```