# Round to hundreds with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to round numbers to hundreds with javascript like this:

```
10651.89    = 10700
10649.89    = 10600
60355.03    = 60400
951479.29   = 951500
1331360.95  = 1331400
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round money to nearest 10 dollars in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463920/round-money-to-nearest-10-dollars-in-javascript), take out the money factor and the fact that question is for tens instead of hundreds and the question is the same.  Even the answers are identical.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
function roundHundred(value){
   return Math.round(value/100)*100
}
```

Live example with your test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/LaPGs/

Comment: It's rounding down to hundreds. I needed the one that rounds up to hundreds. For example, if the value is 230, it returns 300. Thank you.

Comment: @Azamat just use `Math.ceil` in place of `Math.round`

Answer (score 5):

you can divide it by 100 first then use `Math.round`, and finally multiply it by 100.

```
> Math.round(10651.89 / 100) * 100
10700
```

Answer (score 4):

we can use [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) for doing this.

```
var rawNumber = 10651.89;
 roundFigure= Math.ceil(rawNumber /100)*100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function(x) {
  return Math.round(x / 100) * 100;
}
```