# Round numbers in Javascript before decimal point

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

How do you round down a number before the decimal points
So not `45.1 -> 45`
But `47 -> 45`
Or `45 -> 50`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round money to nearest 10 dollars in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463920/round-money-to-nearest-10-dollars-in-javascript)

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. You say that you are rounding down, but you then specify 45 rounding UP to 50. Also what happens when you have decimals?

Comment: Sorry, English isn't my native language, I didn't know you could say rounding up. Thanks for pointing that out. What I meant was how to round to the nearest 5 or to the nearest 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var number = 45.5;
alert(Math.round(number / 5) * 5);
```

This rounds to nearest 5.

```
var number = 45.5;
alert(Math.round(number / 10) * 10);
```

And this to nearest 10.

There is also a function `floor` that rounds to lower number and `ceil` that rounds to higher number` for example:

```
var number = 45.5;
alert(Math.floor(number / 10) * 10); // This will give 40
alert(Math.ceil(number / 10) * 10); // This will give 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```
  Math.round(45/ 10) * 10;
```