# Rounding a number to its nearest 10's place javascript

Tags: javascript

How to round a number to its nearest 10's place? Example if number = 123, then it should be rounded to 100, if it is 175 that is greater than 150 then it should round to 200 , the number will changed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round an integer up or down to the nearest 10 using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684202/how-to-round-an-integer-up-or-down-to-the-nearest-10-using-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
value = 2345;
 log_10 =  parseInt(Math.log(value) / Math.log(10));
                      basePower =  Math.pow(10, log_10); 
                      result = ((((value/basePower)).toFixed(0))* basePower); 
                      alert(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Math.round()` for that. `Math.round()` rounds of the decimals. In order to get decimals in this case we need to divide `a` with 100 (155/100 = 1.55). Now the `Math.round()` will round this number to 2. We can now multiply this number with 100 again to get the correct number. 
Try this:

```
var number = 155;
var rounded = Math.round( number / 100 ) * 100;
```

Answer (score 4):

this is how I would do it,

```
function round10(num){
    var tmp=1;
    while(num>10){
        num = Math.round(num/10);
        tmp*=10;
    }

    return num*tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
var num=230;
num=((num/100).toFixed(0))*100;
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this 
      var num = 175;
      alert(Math.round(num/100)*100);

Answer (score 3):

Divide the number by 100 and round it. Then, multiply by 100.

```
num = Math.round(num / 100) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

**In dart you can:**

```
var number = 143;
var result = (number / 100).round() * 100
```