# How to round to a multiple of a specific number JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to round a number to the nearest multiple of 27 with JavaScript. It would be better if I could always round UP to the number, but it would also be useful to know how to round to the closest multiple of 27 (whether up or down). It doesn't have to be vanilla JavaScript it could be jQuery too.

Comment: You can use `ceil` instead of `round` to round upwards, by the way.

Comment: This has been asked before. Found as the first result by Googling “javascript round number to nearest”.

Comment: @maudulus: You must be joking.

Comment: your simplest solution would be [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27861705/1305910)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide the number by 27, round (or `.ceil` to round it up) the result and multiply by 27:

```js
var x = 28;
console.log('round', Math.round(x/27) * 27);
console.log('ceil', Math.ceil(x/27) * 27);

var y = 47;
console.log('round', Math.ceil(y/27) * 27);
console.log('ceil', Math.round(y/27) * 27);
```