# Round value to next 10 dozen

Tags: javascript

How can I round an integer number in Javascript to the nearest 10? My math is pretty rubbish today :)

Some sample cases:

```
45 = 50
41 = 50
40 = 40
```

I understand I probably need a combination of Math.round/floor but I can't seem to get expected result.

**Any help/pointers appreciated,
thanks**

Comment: do you need a function i can write it for you

Comment: there should be many question like this if you search

Comment: Since when is 10 a dozen??

Comment: i haven't find nothing that answer my question..

Comment: Just a slight change in dupe — `alert(Math.ceil(YOUR_NUMBER / 10) * 10);`

Comment: @AlexBaldwin Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1684207/744534

Answer (score 2):

```
//Update: faster way
var getDozen = function (n) {
    var r = n % 10;
    // if its greater than 4
    if (r > 4)
        return n - r + 10;
    //if its lower than 5, then subtract the remainder
    else
        return n - r;
}
console.log(getDozen(45)); // 50


var getDozen = function (n) {
    var r = n % 10;
    if (r > 4) return Math.ceil(n / 10) * 10;
    else return Math.floor(n / 10) * 10;
}
console.log(getDozen(45)); // 50
```

Comment: You should explain how this answers the OPs question so they can understand your solution.

Comment: it's much simpler than this to be honest.

In the example from Alex, he wants to always round it up to the nearest factor of 10. So, essentially the logic is:
n - (n % 10) + 10 

This is in JS code ---->

if (n % 10 != 0) n - (n % 10) + 10

Comment: % is the reminder operator. So when n is divided by 10, if there is a reminder left (not 0) it means that it has exceeded the round number and it will throw the reminder. For example. 14 % 10 will throw 4. So, if you take 14, then deduct 4, and then add 10, you have the next dozen up which is 20.