# Using moment js to round a given number of minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If I have the number of minutes, say 476, which equals 7 hours and 56 minutes and I need to round this number up to the nearest half hour, so in this instance I need to round 476 so that it equals to 8 hours. How could I do this in moment js?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following logic:

#### Logic:

- Get the total number of hours by dividing minutes by 60.
- Get remainder minutes using `mins % 60`.

  - If `mins` is between `15` and `45`, we can round it to `30`.
  - If it is less than `15` or more than `45, we can round it to` 0`.
  - If `mins` is greater than or equal to `45`, we will increment hour by 1.

```js
function getTime(min){
  var hours = Math.floor(min/60);
  var mins = min % 60;
  console.log('remainder mins: ', mins)
  if(mins >= 15 && mins < 45)
    mins = 30;
  else{
    hours += mins > 45 ? 1 : 0;
    mins = 0;
  }
  return "" + hours + (mins ? ":" + mins : "");
}

console.log(getTime(476))
console.log(getTime(446))
console.log(getTime(426))
console.log(getTime(576))
```

Comment: **Note:** I know OP is looking for a way using moment. In my knowledge (*partial*), there is no function. Hence, above answer represents a math calculation instead of date. If you think there is anything *incorrect/ not appropriate*, feel free to share it in comment section along with your vote. Have a good day!

Comment: It seems moment might not be the best thing to use in this case. This answer is sufficient but I also found this post helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684202/how-to-round-an-integer-up-or-down-to-the-nearest-10-using-javascript