# Javascript round down whole number

Tags: javascript

Im trying round down a whole number, but I cant seem to find a javascript function for this.

I have tried math.floor but this does not do the trick. The number must always be rounded down, not sure if there's an javascript function for this?

Example:

```
29 -> 20
4456 -> 4450
111 -> 110
9 -> 9//the number cant be 0
....

Math.floor(344);//returns 344 (it must be 340)
```

Comment: please add some more examples and the mechanic behind.

Comment: not sure what your trying to show here, your 2nd and 4th example don't have any rounding

Comment: logic seems to be a bit weird here, why does 29 round down to 20, but 4456 stays at 4456?  What rule should the rounding be following?

Comment: Rounding is always to the nearest "something". Typically nearest integer, but it could be to the nearest 10, or nearest 0.1. What are you trying to round to?

Comment: not sure. what you are trying to say

Comment: round down to what? the nearest 10?

Comment: Yes always the nearest 10(down, not up)

Comment: (function F(n){return n < 10 ? ~~n : ~~(n / 10) * 10}(9))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round an integer up or down to the nearest 10 using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684202/how-to-round-an-integer-up-or-down-to-the-nearest-10-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use Math.floor, and simply shift the answer by an order of magnitude:

```
const moreFloor = n => Math.floor (n / 10) * 10 || n;

// (or if you prefer...)
function moreFloor (n) {
    return Math.floor (n / 10) * 10 || n;
}
```

Just to clarify, the `|| n` at the end of the expression is due to the particular requirement in the question to *not* round down any number less than ten. If readers want `moreFloor(9) === 0`, you can omit that part.

Answer (score 2):

You can round to the nearest place by utilizing the power of 10.

```js
function ceil10(n, e) {
  var m = Math.pow(10, e - 1);
  return Math.ceil(n / m) * m || n;
}

function floor10(n, e) {
  var m = Math.pow(10, e - 1);
  return Math.floor(n / m) * m || n;
}

function roundNearestLog(n) {
  var e = Math.ceil(Math.log(n + 1) / Math.LN10),
      m = Math.pow(10, e - 1);
  return Math.floor(n / m) < 5 ? floor10(n, e) : ceil10(n, e);
}

console.log('ceil   3 =', ceil10(344, 3));       // 400
console.log('ceil   2 =', ceil10(344, 2));       // 350
console.log('ceil   1 =', ceil10(344, 1));       // 344
console.log('ceil   0 =', ceil10(344, 0));       // 344
console.log('-------------');
console.log('floor  0 =', floor10(344, 0));      // 344
console.log('floor  1 =', floor10(344, 1));      // 344
console.log('floor  2 =', floor10(344, 2));      // 340 <-- What you want
console.log('floor  3 =', floor10(344, 3));      // 300
console.log('-------------');
console.log('near   3 =', roundNearestLog(3));   //   3
console.log('near  34 =', roundNearestLog(34));  //  30
console.log('near 344 =', roundNearestLog(344)); // 300
console.log('-------------');
console.log('near   6 =', roundNearestLog(6));   //   6
console.log('near  67 =', roundNearestLog(67));  //  70
console.log('near 677 =', roundNearestLog(677)); // 700
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract the remainder part of 10 and check if the value is zero.

```js
function down(v) {
    return v - v % 10 || v;
}


console.log(down(111));
console.log(down(30));
console.log(down(9));
console.log(down(0));
```

Comment: right, where do you see a problem? the prevention of `9` beeing rounded down is prevented by returning the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's weird, but here's my answer.

```
function roundDown(numberToRound) {
  //Check if the number would've rounded to 0
  if (numberToRound < 10) return numberToRound;
  //Return the number minus the difference to the nearest multiple of 10
  return numberToRound - (numberToRound % 10);
}
```