# Round a variable up to the next closest multiple of X

Tags: javascript, math

I'm looking for a way to round up a number to the next closest multiple of 250.  So for example if I had the following JS:

```
var containerHeight = $("#container").height();
```

...And we imagine the value of "containerHeight" was 680px, I would want a way to round up to 750px (if the value was 1007, it should round up to 1250).  I suspect this requires a solution that is more complex than I anticipate.  Or perhaps jQuery has a built in function that will make this feasible?

I suppose this is more of a math question than it is a jQuery question (but my jQuery syntax knowledge is also a bit limited :)

Any ideas / bits of help are greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding in steps of 20 (or X) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627566/rounding-in-steps-of-20-or-x-in-javascript)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
containerHeight = Math.ceil(containerHeight / 250.0) * 250;
```

Comment: Thanks, James! That's perfect.

Comment: It is important to not that this doesn't work for floating point numbers.

Comment: @MatthewMarlin For floating point numbers, this solution works (doesn't add the X.X00000001... thing): https://stackoverflow.com/a/27861660/2441655 (this does rounding rather than ceiling-ing -- but can easily be changed to use ceiling with `Math.ceil`)

Answer (score 7):

```
function NearestMultiple(i, j) {
    alert(Math.ceil(i/ j) * j);
}

NearestMultiple(1007, 250); //returns 1250
```

See example at http://jsfiddle.net/SUya9/1/

Or what James said too!

EDIT: I see you wanted to round up all the time...Updated fiddle, but James got her in 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that would have worked perfectly as well!

Comment: Note that this does not work for floating point numbers. 
http://jsfiddle.net/SUya9/15/

Comment: @MatthewMarlin For floating point numbers, this solution works (doesn't add the X.X00000001... thing): https://stackoverflow.com/a/27861660/2441655 (this does rounding rather than ceiling-ing -- but can easily be changed to use ceiling with `Math.ceil`)

Answer (score 1):

For those that are working with integers, and want a solution that avoids intermediate floating point, use this:

```
int roundedUp = alignment * ((value + alignment - 1) / alignment);
```

or without the division:

```
int  mod = value % alignment;
if (mod > 0)
   value += (alignment - mod);
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
var rounded = Math.ceil(value / round) * round;
```