# Rounding in steps of 20 (or X) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have numbers starting at 50 and ending with 190. The steps are always 20 -->

*50, 70, 90, .... 190*

Now I get a number from a text filed which has to be rounded according to this. So if I get 55, it should become 70, if I get 77, it should be 90. If I get 90, it should of course stay 90. I know how to do it steps of 10:

```
// 55 --> 60
number = Math.ceil(number / 10) * 10
```

How to round the number I get using steps of 20?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a variable up to the next closest multiple of X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280847/round-a-variable-up-to-the-next-closest-multiple-of-x)

Comment: An iterative method could involve something in the form of `quotient=190; while(quotient%n > 1) quot-=20;` as soon as this yields false `quotient+=20;` will be your number.  For example assume n is 75 and start quotient off at 190.  We reduce quotient by 20 within the loop until the condition yields false...

Comment: @JonH: that's terribly inefficient. What if the function should be able to go up to 10 million? At least make it start at 10 and add 20, but then, what if you can also accept negative characters?
Just use `Math.round()`.

Comment: Cerbrus - Of course it is inefficient, its iterative...that was my whole point.  The point is the logic is to get the remainder, it was a hint to OP.

Comment: There is no need to do anything with the remainder.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to round in increments of x, with an offset:

```
function round(number, increment, offset) {
    return Math.ceil((number - offset) / increment ) * increment + offset;
}
round(51,  20, 10) // 70
round(70,  20, 10) // 70
round(99,  20, 10) // 110
round(100, 20, 10) // 110
```

Comment: Works with ceil instead of round!

Comment: @user1856596: Added `ceil` instead of `round`. Thanks for accepting this as the answer ^_^

Comment: :P Now we ended up with the same code, you adapting the `.ceil` and me your offset.
+1 anyway

Comment: @Glutamat: Then that has to be the right code :P Thanks for the +1

Comment: it's rounding..but it's not "smart" rounding.. for example: 
`round(6, 5, 0) // 10 (should be 5)`
`round(8, 5, 0) // 10 (should be 10)`
`round(1, 5, 0) // 5  (should be 0)`

Comment: @vsync: This in't "proper" rounding indeed. OP's requirements meant `ceil` had to be used. Replace `ceil` with `round` to get the results you want.

Comment: @Cerbrus - thank you for replying in such haste! I'm in dire need for such formula.

Comment: @Cerbrus Using the `round` solution, it works as I'd expect for most integers and single decimal values, but so much for multi-decimal values, like `round(10.35, .10)`, where it rounds to `10.3` whereas the same values each *100 (`round(1035, 10)`) result in `1040`, not `1030`. **To clarify, I did switch ceil back to round intentionally here.

Answer (score 2):

```
function round(number,x,o) {
 o = ~~(o);
   return o + Math.ceil((number - o)/ x ) * x 
 }
 console.log(round (55,20,10)) //70
 console.log(round (77,20,10)) //90
 console.log(round (90,20,10)) //90
```

@Cerbrus thx to point that out

Comment: Just add +10 to get the initial "offset" (to fit to the number rule 50, 70, 90...)

Comment: `return Math.round((number-10) / x ) * x + 10` <-- That should do it.

Comment: @OlafWatteroth: added it as an answer.

Comment: This looks promising, if I entered 70 fpr example, it returns 90, but it should stay 70. How do I have to modify that?

Comment: @user1856596: take a look at my answer. For some reason, he's now using `Math.ceil`

Comment: It returns 70 for 70 for me take a look at the [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/efilem/1/edit)

Comment: `round(51,20,10)` is returning `70`, however.

Comment: @Cerbrus shouldn't it be ceil if the OP wants 55 -> 70 , 77 - 90.

Comment: Works, thanks! Can someone explain the o = ~~(o); stuff please?

Comment: It's to cast an `undefined` or `null` value to `0`. `~` is a bitwise `not`, which returns `-1` when applied to `undefined` or `null`. Also, `~ -1 == 0`. So, `~~undefined == 0`. The `()` aren't required.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with something like that

```
number = Math.ceil( (number - 50) / 20 ) * 20 + 50;
```

Comment: This doesn't `round` the number. See the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var number;
var a =number-10-((number-10)%20);
var result=a+30;
// does not work if num is 70 or 90 so
if(result-20==number)
Result=number;
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
var result=number+20-((number-10)%20) - result-20==number : 0 ? 20;
```

The logic is that first, you add 20 to the number. Take the number 77. 77+20=97. But, 77+20-7=90, what you want. And 7 is the difference between 77 and 70, the previous valid number. You can get the differencewith (number-10)%20. However, it doesn't work if number is OK to start out with, hence the logic at the end.