# Round down number to nearest 50000 - input range

Tags: php, html, forms, range

I've got a input range which is teasing be a bit.
The value starts at 0 but it jumps right to 40000 one way and -10000 the other way. I want it to jump 50000 - step indicator is set to 50000. I guess it's because the min and max number is not divided by 50000.

Example:

```
<input name="example" type="range" max="2240000" min="-160000" value="0" step="50000">
```

(The numbers is drawn from a database)

But basicly I want - in this example - the inputfield to round min to -150000 and max to 2200000

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round up to nearest multiple of five in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php)

Comment: Possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627566/rounding-in-steps-of-20-or-x-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If min and max is drawn from database, you need to change it. Example in php:

```
<?php 

$min = -160000;
$max = 2240000;
$step = 50000;

echo $min = intdiv($min , $step) * $step;       
echo '<br>';
echo $max = intdiv($max, $step) * $step;    
?>
```

Output:

```
-150000
2200000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you want `2200000` as max and `-150000` as min why don't you put them in the input?

```
<input name="example" type="range" max="2200000" min="-150000" value="0" step="50000">
```